# RegEx in Python not returning matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract certain lines out of a file if they match certain criteria. Specifically, column [3] needs to start with Chr3:, and column [13] needs to be "yes".

Here are examples of lines that match and do not match the criteria:

> ```
> XLOC_004170   XLOC_004170 -   Ch3:14770-25031 SC_JR32_Female  SC_JR32_Male    OK  55.8796 9.2575  -2.59363    -0.980118   0.49115 0.897554    no
> XLOC_004387   XLOC_004387 -   Ch3:3072455-3073591 SC_JR32_Female  SC_JR32_Male    OK  0   35.4535 inf -nan    5e-05   0.0149954   yes
> ```

The python script I am using is:

```
with open(input_file) as fp: # fp is the file handle
    for line in fp: #line is the iterator
        line=line.split("\t")
        locus = str(line[3])
        significance = str(line[13])
        print(locus)
        print(significance)

        if (re.match('Chr3:[0-9]+-[0-9]+',locus,flags=0) and re.match('yes',significance,flags=0)):
            output.write(("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n")%(line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],line[5],line[6],line[7],line[8],line[9],line[10],line[11],line[12],line[13]))
```

I would really be grateful if anyone could explain why this script returns no outputs.

Comment: From your example "locus" seems to be on index 2, not 3. You can try by simplifying the code (e.g., just testing the regex on the string directly, without the rest of the parsing code).

Comment: Your regex contains Chr3 but locus in your data starts with Ch3. Maybe it is the problem?

Comment: There can be an invisible character at the end of line, e.g. a space or `\r` if the file was created on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex for such simple checks. Better use `startswith()` and `==`:

```
if locus.startswith('Chr3:') and significance == 'yes':
```

UPD:
You need to apply `strip()` on `locus` and `significance` variables before the if condition:

```
locus = str(line[3]).strip()
significance = str(line[13]).strip()
```

Comment: I am definitely using right indexes. There is a hyphen between columns 1 and 3 that is easy to miss. For some reason, the above code does not produce any outputs. I simplified to code to if (locus.startswith('Chr3:')): but it still gives no outputs. This makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: Could you try `locus.startswith('Ch3:')`? (see zero323's comment)

Comment: I tried it, but there was still no output. Makes no sense at all. I don't know what I am missing. I am importing the string, sys and re modules. Do I need another module?

Comment: ok. what if you call `strip()` on desired items: `locus = str(line[3]).strip()` and `significance = cells[12].strip()`?

Comment: The .strip() seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @gwilymh great! Consider accepting the answer if you think it deserves, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no reason to use regex here:

```
with open(input_file) as handle:
    for line in handle:
        cells = line.split('\t')

        locus = cells[2]
        significance = cells[12]

        if locus.startswith('Ch3:') and significance == 'yes':
            output.write('\t'.join(cells) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks Blender. Elegant code, but it just does not work. It should have picked up the line: "XLOC_005846 XLOC_005846 - Ch3:3762392-3764209 SC_JR32_Female SC_JR32_Male OK 0 24.1085 inf -nan 5e-05 0.0149954 yes
"
 but for no reason I can perceive it does not.

Comment: @gwilymh: Print out  `repr(locus)` and `repr(significance)`.